# always show red error when using immediate invocation js with event listener

Tags: javascript, html

I have here five input that is supposed to be written in each one is matching the value with the conditions in the js code to verify but after searching and checking I did not find a better way to use addEventListener It is assumed when the input is correct to put hello in green and It was not red, but it always appears red, and I can not show a message based on input, I always make mistakes when using the loop.

> JavaScriptCode

```
    var form = document.getElementById('formone');
    var allFormInput = form.elements;
    var message = 'hello';
    for (var i = 0; i < allFormInput.length; i++){
      var inputloop = allFormInput[i];
      (function () {allFormInput[i].addEventListener("input",valiform)}());
      function valiform(){
        if(inputloop.value == "" || inputloop.value.indexOf("<") !== -1 || inputloop.value.indexOf(">") !== -1 ||typeof(inputloop.value) == null || typeof(inputloop.value) == 'undefined'){
          document.getElementById('errorUser').innerHTML = '<h1 style=\"color:red\;\">'+ message +'</h1>';
        }
        else if(inputloop.value.search(/\s/g) > -1)
        {
        document.getElementById('errorUser').innerHTML = '<h1 style=\"color:red\;\">'+ message +'</h1>';
        }
        else {
        document.getElementById('errorPassC').innerHTML = '<h1 style=\"color:green\;\">'+ message +'</h1>';
        }
      }

    }
```

> HTML CODE

```
<?php require "header.php" ?>
  <main>
    <scetion class="section-default">
        <form id="formone" onsubmit="return valiform();" name="signform" class="signup-form" action="includes/signup.inc.php" method="post" >
          <input type="text" name="unm" placeholder="Username" minlength="6" maxlength="20" required />
          <span id="errorUser"></span>
          <br/>
          <input type="email" name="mail" placeholder="E-mail" minlength="6" maxlength="20" required/>
          <br/>
          <input type="password" name="pwdr" placeholder="Password" minlength="6" maxlength="20" required/>
          <span id="errorPass"></span>
          <br/>
          <input type="password" name="pwdrc" placeholder="Confirm Password" minlength="6" maxlength="20" required/>
          <span id="errorPassC"></span>
          <br/>
          <button type="submit" name="signupsubmit">SignUp</button>
        </form>
    </scetion>
  </main>
<?php require "footer.php" ?>
```

Comment: Much of this is already done for you by the browser. For styling valid/invalid content review [Styling Constraint Validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation#Visual_styling_of_constraint_validation) - and more generally [Constraint Validation (form validation)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation)

Comment: it's not about valid/invalid style its about validate js code